# I have a question for grammaticality

Tags: grammaticality

This book's name is "outliers"

The explanation for this is quite simple. It has nothing to do with astrology, nor is there anything magical about the first three months of the year. It's simply that in Canada the eligibility cutoff for age-class hockey is January 1. A boy turns ten on January 2, then could be playing alongside someone who doesn't turn ten until the year - and at that age, in pre-adolescence, a twelve-month gap in age represents an enormous difference in physical maturity.
This being Canada, the most hockey-crazed country on earth, coaches start to select players for the traveling "rep" squad-the all-star teams-at the age of nine or ten, and of course they are more-likely to view as talented the bigger and more coordinated players, who have had the benefic of critical extra month of maturity.
And what happens when a player gets chosen for a red squad? He gets better coaching, and his team-mates are better, and he plays fifty or seventy-five games a season instead of twenty games a season like those left behind in the "house" league, and he practices twice as much as, or even three times more than, he would have otherwise. In the beginning, his advantage isn't so much that he is inherently better **but only that** he is a little older

What I'm curious about is this.

1. but only that(bolded) -> As I found a dictionary, "but" means "except that" and "only that" means the same. if so, "but only that" is duplication of words with the same meaning so grammatically wrong,
   doesn't it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Except that* isn't the only meaning of *but*! See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but)

> I can't play the piano **but** I can sing.

> His advantage is **not** that he is a better player **but** that he is older.

Comment: As I understood, He isn't inherently better but merely he is a little older, right??

Comment: See the earlier sentences. A boy born early in the year is a little older than the ones born later the same year, even though they are officially 'the same age'.

Comment: Thank you for answer